# Netsuite insert phoneCall to supportcase not working

Tags: netsuite, netsuite-rest-api

I want to add a phonecall to one of my supportcases.
When I use the following request, I get an error.

```
POST https://[CN].suitetalk.api.netsuite.com/services/rest/record/v1/phoneCall
```

The body:

```
{
  "title":"test",
  "message": "test call",
  "phone": "+3101234567",
  "supportcase": 555
}
```

The error:

```
{
    "type": "https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.1",
    "title": "Bad Request",
    "status": 400,
    "o:errorDetails": [
        {
            "detail": "Error while accessing a resource. You have entered an Invalid Field Value 555 for the following field: supportcase.",
            "o:errorCode": "USER_ERROR"
        }
    ]
}
```

The documentation isn't clear enough, does someone know what I should use as value for the supportCase property?
I tried the `caseNumber` and also the `internal ID`.
Documentation: https://system.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/APIs/REST_API_Browser/record/v1/2021.2/index.html#/definitions/phoneCall

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I try to add the related `company` as well, it works.

```
{
  "title":"test 12",
  "message": "test note",
  "phone": "+31642937986",
  "supportCase": 555,
  "company": 12
}
```

The property `company` has to be send too, also the `supportCase` should be linked to that `company` for it to work

I had to use both `internal Id's`

Answer (score 0):

`supportCase` is an object with its own definition - a 'nested property' if you will.  Try:

```
{
    "title":"test",
    "message": "test call",
    "phone": "+3101234567",
    "supportcase": {
        "caseNumber": 555
    }
}
```

Comment: Then I get a similar but different error: `Invalid value for the resource or sub-resource field 'supportCase'. Provide a valid value.`

Comment: OK, I haven't tested it - I was just looking at the documentation, but a different error is some kind of progress.  The docs actually specify that `caseNumber` should be a `string`, so try `"casenumber": "555"`  (assuming that '555' is a valid support case id in your account)

Comment: There's also `id` which is the internal id, so maybe try that instead.

Comment: if I try `id` or `caseNumber` I still get the same error. It feels like im close but still missing something.